# Cache directory permission is set to root

Tags: php, apache

httpd server(`apache`) run by `app` user/group.

I have Symfony project which makes the cache files.

However server made files under cache directory owened by `root` instead of `app`

It causes the problem when next deployment.

Why these happens??

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 40960 12月 28 14:58 2018 ContainerXNrF7L0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6426 12月 28 14:58 2018 annotations.map
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 12月 28 14:50 2018 doctrine
drwxrwxrwx 10 app  app   4096 12月 28 14:58 2018 pools
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   748 12月 28 14:58 2018 srcProdProjectContainer.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 27444 12月 28 14:58 2018 srcProdProjectContainer.php.meta
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How does `app` write to `root`? Set sane ownership, do VCS update, still work? What is concern?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/chmod-gs-command might help. I'd think you would be getting write errors when creating the cache... Intrigued by the `月`....

Comment: @ficuscr yes, application works , but when updating by capistrano by 'app' user. it can't delete the old folder because of permission.